# No padding between menu items icon and text on some Samsung devices

Tags: android

On our app there is an issue with (some) Samsung devices only. The option menu is a simple  with some s which only have id, icon, title and sometimes some show/visibility ids.
The menu itself uses a default android scheme, no custom styles are defined / used in the menu.

The menu is inflated via code because it is accessible everywhere in the app via the menu button of the device (or in newer versions also the I think it is called overflow button in the action bar)
Inflating the menu item via code makes it hard to figure out issues caused by surrounding layouts if that's a possibility.

The issue is as follows:
For every item in the menu there is a padding between the icon and the left border and the same/similiar padding between icon and text of the item, however on some (older) Samsung devices, e.g. S3, S4 but for example not on the S5 the padding between icon and title is missing.

Is this a known Samsung issue which can't be fixed?

**Update**
The menu is pretty much like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    android:icon="@drawable/draw1"
    android:title="@string/title1"
    android:visible="false"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:icon="@drawable/draw2"
    android:title="@string/title2" />

</menu>
```

There should be a padding between icon and title but it is not on SOME! Samsung devices (at least) but on other devices it is.

Comment: put a screenshot of how you want it and how is it right now

Comment: I don't know if I can post it because it is a app and I don't know if I am allowed too..

Ill update the main post tho

Comment: @ftb I have similar issue. I can set padding between items, but Samsung device seems to ignore padding for overflow item. Overflow item is to close to right edge of the screen. Look at this https://www.dropbox.com/s/1yt85syw8vtzo16/Screenshot_2014-12-10-15-34-45.png?dl=0

Comment: well another issue is that I dont think having your own paddings in stuff within an element (item being an element which i want to be displayed different) is not possible..